Real-time data for option on Taifex
Some time ago I used the link and was able to use the bid- and ask-price data in real time. In particular, the ref provided information on the TХO contract on the Taiwan Exchange.

Question: is there still such an opportunity to view the option's data on Taiwan Exchange or download the data via API.
